# Why are hexadecimal numbers prefixed with 0x?

Tags: c, syntax, hex

Why are hexadecimal numbers prefixed as `0x`?
 I understand the usage of the prefix but I don't understand the significance of why `0x` was chosen.

Comment: Now I realize that the title and the text ask two entirely different questions. Most replies focus on the question in the title. The answer to the question in the text is simply "it does not mean anything - it is merely a prefix telling the compiler that the integer is written in hexadecimal".

Comment: To be pedantic, one might also interpret the question in the title in two different ways: 1) "Why are hexadecimal numbers prefixed as 0x, as opposed to any other prefix or indicator?" 2) "Why do we need to use a prefix when entering hexadecimal numbers? Surely the compiler will recognize 58A as a hexadecimal number even without the prefix?"

The answer to the second interpretation of the question is trivial. "123" is also a hexadecimal number.

Comment: Why the prefix 0x denotes hex number, instead of 0h?

Answer (score 576, accepted):

**Short story:** The `0` tells the parser it's dealing with a constant (and not an identifier/reserved word). Something is still needed to specify the number base: the `x` is an arbitrary choice.

**Long story:** In the 60's, the prevalent programming number systems were decimal and *octal* — mainframes had 12, 18, 24 or 36 bits per byte, which is nicely divisible by 3 = log2(8).

The BCPL language used the syntax `8 1234` for octal numbers. When Ken Thompson created B from BCPL, he used the `0` prefix instead. This is great because

1. an integer constant now always consists of a single token,
2. the parser can still tell right away it's got a constant,
3. the parser can immediately tell the base (`0` is the same in both bases),
4. it's mathematically sane (`00005 == 05`), and
5. no precious special characters are needed (as in `#123`).

When C was created from B, the need for hexadecimal numbers arose (the PDP-11 had 16-bit words and 8-bit bytes) and all of the points above were still valid. Since octals were still needed for other machines, `0x` was arbitrarily chosen (`00` or `0h` was probably ruled out as awkward).

C# is a descendant of C, so it inherits the syntax.

You can find details about the history of C at [Dennis M. Ritchie's page](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www).

Comment: I don't think `0x` over `00` was preference/awkwardness. `00` would break existing code. `0010` as octal is `8`, while `0010` as hexidecimal would be `16`. They couldn't use any number as a second digit indicator (except `8` or `9`, and neither holds any significance related to hexidecimal) so a letter is a must. And that leaves either `0h` or `0x` (**H** e **X** idecimal). From this point it seems it's truly back to preference.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18987911/bcpl-octal-numerical-constants and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483216/why-are-leading-zeroes-used-to-represent-octal-numbers

Comment: Using a `0` prefix for octal has caused so very many problems over the years. Notably in countries like the UK where telephone numbers start with a `0`. Javascript and many other languages would parse these as octal, mangling the number before storing.  To add to the fun, one popular database product would _silently_ switch back to decimal parsing if the number contained an `8` or `9`.

Comment: 12, 24 and 36 are also divisible by 4 so why didn't they think of hexadecimal for that?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Probably because hexadecimal wasn't very relevant. Most of the hardware, software, and documentation of the time fit octal much better. BCPL was first implemented on a [36 bit IBM 7094](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_7090#IBM_7094), with an instruction format split into two 3 bit parts and 2 15 bit parts; 6 bit characters; and documentation in octal. B's early implementations were on a PDP-7 (18 bit) and a Honeywell GE-945 (36 bit, but with 18 bit addressing, and support for 6 and 9 bit bytes). The 16 bit PDP-11 came out after B, so would not have influenced B's design much.

Comment: What do you mean "the parser can immediately tell the base (0 is the same in both bases).". If it's teh same in octal and decimal... how can you tell the base?

Comment: @Jwan622 It can tell because in decimal integer constants the first digit _must not_ be `0`, whereas octal constant integers _must_ start with a `0`.

Comment: Why the prefix 0x denotes hex number, instead of 0h?

Comment: @DawnSong, because it's hexadecimal (base [6+10]) rather than heximal (base 6) :-)

Comment: It's a little-known fact that, every time you put a literal `0` in your C source, it's an *octal* zero. It just happens to be a happy coincidence that this is the same value as a decimal zero :-)

Comment: Thompson could have instead selected "123hd" for hexadecimals and "101b" for binary. Integers are still a single token, the parser can still know it's not an identifier because of the leading digit, the parser can just store the number as a string until it reaches the end of the token, it's even more "mathematically sane" to never ever risk combining different bases, no special characters are used, AND you get two essential properties: (1) Leading zeroes in numbers-as-strings can't accidentally change the interpreted base, and (2) no more meaningless `0` character RIGHT next to real zeroes.

Comment: Anyway folks this is why code should never ever be edited as text and we needed structural editors 20 years ago.

Comment: I don't see how you can call 'x' an "arbitrary choice". "x" sounds like"hex" when you say it, except without the 'h', which some important languages and dialects don't pronounce in words anyway.

Answer (score 119):

*Note:  I don't know the correct answer, but the below is just my personal speculation!*

As has been mentioned a 0 before a number means it's octal:

```
04524 // octal, leading 0
```

Imagine needing to come up with a system to denote hexadecimal numbers, and note we're working in a C style environment.  How about ending with h like assembly?  Unfortunately you can't - it would allow you to make tokens which are valid identifiers (eg. you could name a variable the same thing) which would make for some nasty ambiguities.

```
8000h // hex
FF00h // oops - valid identifier!  Hex or a variable or type named FF00h?
```

You can't lead with a character for the same reason:

```
xFF00 // also valid identifier
```

Using a hash was probably thrown out because it conflicts with the preprocessor:

```
#define ...
#FF00 // invalid preprocessor token?
```

In the end, for whatever reason, they decided to put an x after a leading 0 to denote hexadecimal.  It is unambiguous since it still starts with a number character so can't be a valid identifier, and is probably based off the octal convention of a leading 0.

```
0xFF00 // definitely not an identifier!
```

Comment: Interesting. I imagine they could have used a leading 0 AND trailing h to denote hex. The trailing h probably would have been confused with the type specifier suffix, e.g. 0xFF00l vs 0FF00hl

Comment: This argument implies that the use of a leading zero to denote octal numbers predates the use of the hexadecimal "0x" prefix. Is this true?

Comment: Wouldn't they have both been invented at the same time?  Why would there ever be one but not the other?

Comment: AshleysBrain see answer by @Řrřola for why there could be octal but not hexadecimal at the same time.

Comment: @zdan they have used it long time ago. In x86 Intel assembly a hex literal must always be prefixed by 0 if they begin with a character. For example `0xFFAB1234` must be written as `0FFAB1234h`. I remember it from inline asm in Pascal when I was young http://stackoverflow.com/q/11733731/995714

Comment: Assembly languages that do support the trailing-h syntax *do* require numeric literals to start with a 0-9 digit, for the same reason you say it would be a problem in C.  `DEADBEEFh` is a symbol name, `AH` is an x86 register name!  Thus **[assemblers support `0FF00h` and/or `0xFF00`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11733731/how-to-represent-hex-value-such-as-ffffffbb-in-x86-inline-assembly-programming/37152498#37152498), but *not* `FF00h`**

Comment: As you said, 0h might be better than 0x. Why is 0x chosen finally?

Answer (score 41):

It's a prefix to indicate the number is in hexadecimal rather than in some other base. The programming language uses it to tell compiler.

**Example:**

`0x6400` translates to  `6*16^3 + 4*16^2 + 0*16^1 +0*16^0 = 25600.`
When compiler reads `0x6400`, It understands the number is hexadecimal with the help of **0x**  term.  Usually we can understand by (6400)<sub>16</sub> or (6400)<sub>8</sub> or whatever ..

For ***binary*** it would be:

`0b00000001`

**Good day!**

Comment: Binary literals are only supported in C++ since C++14, and not supported in C at all.

Comment: This doesn't explain *why*. Particularly, why couldn't you write the first example as `x6400`? The `x` could still be used to infer hexadecimal.

Answer (score 20):

The preceding 0 is used to indicate a number in base 2, 8, or 16.

In my opinion, 0x was chosen to indicate hex because 'x' sounds like hex.

Just my opinion, but I think it makes sense.

Good Day!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I understand that this is your first post on StackOverflow.  The answer could have been more helpful if opinions are separated from facts.

Comment: This answer does a great job of separating opinions from facts.

Comment: I appreciate the very plausible idea that "x" rhymes with "hex" which is a common way to refer to a hexadecimal number. This is the only answer that mentions it.

Answer (score 14):

I don't know the historical reasons behind `0x` as a prefix to denote hexadecimal numbers - as it certainly could have taken many forms. This particular prefix style is from the early days of computer science.

As we are used to decimal numbers there is usually no need to indicate the *base/radix*. However, for programming purposes we often need to distinguish the bases from binary (base-2), octal (base-8), decimal (base-10) and hexadecimal (base-16) - as the most commonly used number bases.

At this point in time it is a convention used to denote the base of a number. I've written the number 29 in all of the above bases with their prefixes:

- `0b11101`: Binary
- `0o35`: Octal, denoted by an o
- `0d29`: Decimal, this is unusual because we assume numbers without a prefix are decimal
- `0x1D`: Hexadecimal

Basically, an alphabet we most commonly associate with a base (e.g. b for binary) is combined with `0` to easily distinguish a number's base.

This is especially helpful because smaller numbers can confusingly appear the same in all the bases: 0b1, 0o1, 0d1, 0x1.

If you were using a rich text editor though, you could alternatively use subscript to denote bases: 1<sub>2</sub>, 1<sub>8</sub>, 1<sub>10</sub>, 1<sub>16</sub>

Comment: Why 0h is not chosen for hex? 0x seems strange.

Comment: @DawnSong It's just a convention that is quite popular and now we have to live with it. Sometimes these things are arbitrary. You could try promoting your way, but it's hard to change the habits of so many people. I find the Octal one to be the most confusing visually.