# where does 0x come from?

Tags: history, multilingual

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are Hexadecimal Prefixed as 0x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670639/why-are-hexadecimal-prefixed-as-0x)

I just saw a comment a friend of mine made:

```
3x12=36
2x12=24
1x12=12
0x12=18
```

Which made me wonder..
Why did they choose `0x` as prefix for hexadecimal numbers? Is there any history behind this decision?

Comment: you mean what is the history of 0x as a prefix vor hex-numbers?

Comment: @Hinek: exactly. why `0x` and not `0?` or `_` or any other character..

Comment: different languages systems actually have [a lot of ways](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal#Representing_hexadecimal) to represent hexadecimal, both prefix and suffix, using `0`, `h` and even `$` and `\\`.

Comment: In C you can type in numbers in three formats:
A: decimal -> starting with 1 to 9
B: octal starting with 0 (like 037)
C: hexadecimal starting with 0x
One only needed some seperation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, because `x` comes from `hex` and `0` is to indicate that it is a number.

Comment: So it would be possible to have something like `ax` to describe characters? Never heard of. :) This answer seems most reasonable though, thanks

Comment: @Default: No, but you could have `0xa`.

Comment: `0xa` would still be a number. I merely suggested that, if it was to indicate a number (to use 0) could you then use a character (for instance a) to indicate a [hexadecimal] character?

Comment: @Default: If you wrote a compiler that accepted it, sure you could. That's really a decision that goes to the language designer.

Comment: @Default It would be complicated if `axac` is a hex number, and `axag` a variable name, so language designers mostly choose `0x` as a hex.

Answer (score 1):

`0x` means the number is probably hexadecimal. This applies in C/C++, and probalby other 
languages.

His comment is a joke. he starts with multiplication tables for the number 12, but when he gets to 0 he implies that `0x` is not "0 multiplied by...", but instead is "hexadecimal" so 12 in hex is 18 in decimal.

Answer (score 0):

It's a joke on HEX numbers from [WIKIPEDIA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal).

> The first three are interpreted as
>   multiplication, but in the last, "0x"
>   signals Hexadecimal interpretation of
>   12, which is 18.

Answer (score 0):

'0x' means that the number that follows is in hexadecimal. It's a way of unambiguously stating that a number is in hex, and is a notation recognised by C compilers and some assemblers