# what does 0X mean?

Tags: javascript

what does 0X mean? I saw it mentioned in class, but my teacher had no idea either. Is it synonymous to the word hexadecimal or does it mean all values? Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: what kind of code is that anyway?

Comment: Probably a prefix to a hexadecimal number. Hard to say without seeing code.

Comment: 0x on it's own doesn't mean much, if you say 0x023 it is the hexadecimal equivalent of 35

Comment: I'm surprised no one has flagged this as a duplicate seeing as how 9/10 of legitimate questions get voted to close. [Why are Hexadecimal Prefixed as 0x?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670639/why-are-hexadecimal-prefixed-as-0x) [where does 0x come from?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257661/where-does-0x-come-from)

Comment: [What do numbers using 0x notation mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8186965/995714)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, it means the following value is in hexadecimal:

```
var num = 0xFF; //255  -  1111 1111
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it means the value that comes after '0x' is interpreted as a hexadecimal value.

```
var a = 0x123;
console.log(a); // output is ((16^2)*1) + ((16^1)*2) + ((16^0)*3) = 291
```

See also [What do numbers using 0x notation mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186965/what-do-numbers-using-0x-notation-mean)

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 6):

It means the subsequent characters in the token should be interpreted as heXadecimal

```
0x20
```

means the decimal value

```
32
```

Answer (score 4):

`0x` is how you denote a hexadecimal string in JavaScript, e.g. `0xFFFFFF`

Comment: Not only in JS. Almost everywhere...