# What do numbers using 0x notation mean?

Tags: c, integer, hex, notation

What does a `0x` prefix on a number mean?

```
const int shared_segment_size = 0x6400;
```

It's from a C program. I can't recall what it amounts to and particularly what the letter `x` means.

Comment: Search for "hexadecimal notation"

Comment: @asawyer Thanks. Before I picked up "0x" as hexadecimal, I had no idea where to search from though.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

Literals that start with `0x` are hexadecimal integers. (base 16)

The number `0x6400` is `25600`.

```
6 * 16^3 + 4 * 16^2 = 25600
```

For an example including letters (also used in hexadecimal notation where A = 10, B = 11 ... F = 15)

The number `0x6BF0` is `27632`.

```
6 * 16^3 + 11 * 16^2 + 15 * 16^1 = 27632
24576    + 2816      + 240       = 27632
```

Comment: What I was wondering about, how should negative numbers be denoted in hex? Like -0xff or 0x-ff? I guess the first, but I don't know.

Comment: @Luc The first one is correct. Although more often I see just `0xffffffff` and such. (`0xffffffff = -1` for 32-bit int assuming 2's complement)

Comment: @Luc Negatives numbers are represented in binary using *2's complement*- a clever way that does not require '-' sign. So, it's basically converting from binary to hex, negative or positive.

Comment: @ShuvoSarker Thanks for the addition! That's just the memory representation though, I guess similar to if we would agree that we have a set of numbers from 0--999 and that 1000--1999 would represent the negative numbers. My question was about human-readable notation, though knowing how computers do it might help someone else, so thanks :)

Comment: You need to fix this answer. The first sentence is misleading in the extreme. Literals that start with `0x` can also obviously be IEEE 754 floating point values, as in hexadecimal exponential notation. Your answer would suggest otherwise and currently deserves a downvote.

Answer (score 25):

In C and languages based on the C syntax, the prefix `0x` means hexadecimal (base 16).

Thus, 0x400 = 4×(16<sup>2</sup>) + 0×(16<sup>1</sup>) + 0×(16<sup>0</sup>) = 4×((2<sup>4</sup>)<sup>2</sup>) = 2<sup>2</sup> × 2<sup>8</sup> = 2<sup>10</sup> = 1024, or one binary K.

And so 0x6400 = 0x4000 + 0x2400 = 0x19×0x400 = 25K

Answer (score 10):

It's a hexadecimal number.

> 0x6400 translates to 4*16^2 + 6*16^3 = 25600

Answer (score 9):

The numbers starting with `0x` are hexadecimal (base 16).`0x6400` represents `25600`.

To convert,

- multiply the last digit times 1
- add second-last digit times 16 (16^1)
- add third-last digit times 256 (16^2)
- add fourth-last digit times 4096 (16^3)
- ...and so on

The factors 1, 16, 256, etc. are the increasing powers of 16.

```
0x6400 = (0*1) + (0*16^1) + (4*16^2) + (6*16^3) = 25600
```

or

```
0x6400 = (0*1) + (0*16) + (4*256) + (6*4096) = 25600
```

Answer (score 8):

**SIMPLE**

It's a prefix to indicate the number is in hexadecimal rather than in some other base. The C programming language uses it to tell compiler.

**Example:**

`0x6400` translates to `6*16^3 + 4*16^2 + 0*16^1 +0*16^0 = 25600.` When compiler reads `0x6400`, It understands the number is hexadecimal with the help of 0x term. Usually we can understand by `(6400)16 or (6400)8` or any base.