# Representation of integers in MIPS

Tags: mips, mips32

Let's say I have the integer 19 in MIPS,

It would look like this in binary: `000000000000000000000000000010011`

It would look like this in hexadecimal: `00000013`

But in MIPS, it is shown as `0x 000000013`

My question is: what does `0x` represent in MIPS?

Comment: The prefix `0x` is just a very common notation for hexadecimal, to distinguish it form decimal or other bases.

Comment: In binary (machine code) there are only 1 and 0, no 00000013 or 0x00000013 or something like that. They are only human reading symbols in assembly and many other languages, not exist in machine code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186965/what-do-numbers-using-0x-notation-mean

Answer (score 4):

`0x` signifies that the number format is hexadecimal.

It's not something you will only see in mips either, it's fairly common that if a number is preceded by `0x`, then it is a hexadecimal number.

Also for clarification, `0x` itself does not have any actual value, it just means the number is hexadecimal