# What does asm instruction 'ta' & '0xfffffffc' mean?

Tags: java, assembly, jvm

See the following code from `jdk8/openjdk/hotspot/src/os_cpu/linux_sparc/vm/linux_sparc.s`:

```
_flush_reg_windows:
    ta 0x03
    retl
    mov     %fp, %o0
```

What does the code above mean?

I can't understand what `ta` means.

Also, why there exists code after `retl`. Nothing should exist after `ret`, right?

In the instruction `mov %fp, %o0` what does `%o0` mean? Does `%fp` refer to FramePointer FP register?

Plus, another small question:

```
mov    %eax, 0xfffffffc(%ebp)
```

What does `0xfffffffc` here mean?

Comment: Reffer the manual of assembly language of Sparc at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19641-01/802-1947/802-1947.pdf   You need to know a lot about assembly language and machine language of Sparc.

Comment: _"what does '0xfffffffc' mean?"_ `0x` is a prefix used for [hexadecimal literals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal).

Comment: Read more about [sparc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPARC) architecture. There's no common architecture for all CPUs

Comment: about the second question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186965/what-do-numbers-using-0x-notation-mean http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670639/why-are-hexadecimal-prefixed-as-0x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your question correctly you are not really aware of the fact that different processor architectures (like x86, ARM, Sparc, MIPS, PowerPC) use a completely different instruction set.

For this reason assembler code (and instructions) for these processors will look absolutely different.

The first fragement of code is obviously Sparc assembly code. Sparc processors were used in larger Sun (now Oracle) workstations. The way these processors work is very different to x86 processors used in a PC.

Registers are named %o0-%o7, %g0-%g7, %l0-%l7 and %i0-%i7 on such processors. %fp is the "special name" of one of these registers (%i6 = %fp).

Just like MIPS processors such CPUs have "delay slots". This means that a Jump, Call or Return instruction will execute with one instruction delay. This means the instruction following a jump or ret instruction is executed before the actual jump takes place.

For this reason there is an instruction after the "retl" instruction!

The "ta" instruction is similar to the "int" instruction on x86 CPUs: It executes an operating system interrupt.

As "Michael" already set 0xFFFFFFFC is a hexadecimal number; in this case -4.

"mov %eax,0xfffffffc(%ebp)" is code for x86 CPUs. The instruction will load a value that is stored at the address ebp-4 into the register eax.

Comment: Very thanks,it is just what I needed.Thank you very much.@Martin Rosenau

Comment: Wrong! `mov %eax,0xfffffffc(%ebp)` is in AT&T syntax, which moves the value stored in eax to the address ebp+0xfffffffc, not the other way around

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc You are right; I turned the two arguments around. Sorry for that.