# What does this mean like "0x15000 bytes", what type of encoding is this 0x123?

Tags: python, encoding, byte, analytics

Hello I'm currently exploring some things and want to expand my knowledge about programming stuff.
I have seen stuff like this `0x555` in different places and I just need to know what is this used for and what is it?

I used a `Python` program to analyze a file and I got this info, would be good if someone would explain what this means as well.

```
# Found start marker of lengthh 7
# Found start marker at offset: 0x42413
# Found end marker of length 7
# Found end marker at offset: 0x57413
# Found decoy document end marker at offset: 0x5CC1A
# Grabbing 0x15000 bytes for payload decryption...
        .. decrypting payload
# Grabbing 0x5800 bytes for decoy decryption..
        .. decrypting decoy
# Processing complete.
```

And by the way can someone provide me a good tutorial or ebook for learning more about shellcodes, xor, bytes etc. ?
Thanksi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do numbers using 0x notation mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186965/what-do-numbers-using-0x-notation-mean)

Comment: Welcome to SO, please make a search before asking a question. Regarding shellcodes, xor, bytes etc. a basic Google search will lead you a ton of well-written tutorials and examples.

Comment: They are hex numbers. valid digits 0123456789ABCDEF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are numbers, just like you're familiar with: 1, 2, 3, and so on.

But they are written in hexadecimal instead of decimal. In decimal, we have 10 digits: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, and 9. In hexadecimal, we have 16. The first 10 are the same as listed before. The six new ones are A, B, C, D, E, and F.

What this means is that in decimal, we count ...8, 9, 10, 11..., but in hexadecimal, we count ...8, 9, A, B.... And in hexadecimal we count ...E, F, 10, 11, when in decimal we could be counting ...14, 15, 16, 17....

The reason hexadecimal is used is because 16, unlike 10, is a power of 2, and computers love powers of two.

Think of it like this. Computers work in binary, and if you have four bits (BInary DIgits) you'll write something like `1001`. Simple enough. But with one single hexadecimal digit, you can compactly write 4 bits all at once.

The reason is that there are 16 possible combinations of four bits, from `0000` to `1111`. All we have done is mapped those sixteen combinations onto the sixteen digits of the hexadecimal system. So, 0 in hex = 0 in binary, while A in hex = `1010` in binary (= 10 in decimal).

This compactness is the reason why hexadecimal is used so often. One byte (eight bits) can be represented with two hexadecimal digits. Since computer memory is always addressed by bytes or multiples of bytes, memory addresses are easily expressed using hexadecimal. Likewise, many quantities related to computing, such as quantities of data, are usually multiples of bytes as well.

`0x` is a prefix used to specify that the number coming after it is in hexadecimal. This is needed because some hexadecimal numbers look just like decimal numbers, e.g. 32.

Another you might see is the octal system. All the same concept above apply, except that the prefix is just a single `0`. And which octal, you can write 3 bits compactly instead of 4.

Hope this helps!