# What does 0x mean before a number?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

Does anyone knows why people using 0x before number?

For example:

```
mov ah, 0x16

mov ah, 16
```

There is a difference between them?

Comment: `0x` is hexadecimal (base 16). Without the `0x` you get decimal (base 10). This syntax has nothing to do with it being a `mov` instruction.

Comment: It is a C syntax thing that has migrated into other languages.  Not sure if it actually started with C or if C got it from prior languages (B? other?)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670639 indicates it started with C not BCPL nor B.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do numbers using 0x notation mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186965/what-do-numbers-using-0x-notation-mean)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`0x` implies it's a hex literal, `0x16` is 22 decimal.