# Script to convert MiB/KiB to Hex '0x' notation and do additions (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex

Trying to understand hexadecimal `0x` notation in regards to memory locations and sizes in MiB (mebibytes) and KiB (kibibytes). Specifically, in a partition layout table I can see the following columns:

```
size        hex '0x' notation           
1 MiB       0x0010 0000    
12 MiB      0x00c0 0000
128 KiB     0x0002 0000
```

But I find it hard to translate/extract the logic to calculate and do the conversions for myself (for example convert from 24 MiB, 125 KiB, 16 MiB, to '0x' hex notation etc.).

Hence, I thought of writing a **`Python` script (as you do) to do the conversions from MiB/KiB to 'Ox' and additions of '0x'**. I found this [https://stackoverflow.com/a/8186974/6167676] but I failed to do anything meaningful from it.

To my surprise I could not find something online to help me do the conversions from MiB/KiB to the hex '0x' notation. In `Python` I found the `hex` function in an attempt to do basic additions between hex values in the hex '0x' notation:

```
def hex_add(h1, h2):
    return hex(int(h1, 0) + int(h2, 0))
```

How can use `Python` (built-in or not functions) to automatically calculate the conversion from MiB to the hex '0x' notation? Also, is the `hex_add` adequate to perform additions on '0x' notation?

Some code examples to demonstrate the conversion and addition in `Python` would be very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's create some constants for KiB, MiB, GiB, etc. Don't worry about hex here, we just want the numbers in whatever form makes most sense to you—whether that's `1024` or `0x400` or `2**10` doesn't matter, since those are all the same number. So:

```
KiB = 1024
MiB = 1024 * KiB
GiB = 1024 * MiB
TiB = 1024 * GiB
```

Now, how much is 12MiB? Easy:

```
12 * MiB
```

Now, how much is 12MiB in hex?

```
hex(12 * MiB)
```

This gives you `'0xc00000'`.

---

As far as "adding in hex", that's not a thing you should do. Just add the numbers as numbers, then format the result in hex. For example, if you want to add 32KiB + 16KiB + 1MiB:

```
hex(32*KiB + 16*KiB + 1*MiB)
```

---

You wanted a bit more control over the output. If that's important, you'll need to use [format strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) (whether via the `format` function, the `str.format` method, or f-string literals) instead of `hex`.

You can specify a width to pad to, and a fill character to pad with. And you can use `#` to add the `0x` automatically (in which case we have to pad to 8+2=10 characters instead of 8), or add the `0x` manually (in which case we only have to pad to 8 characters, which makes a bit more sense):

```
format(12 * MiB, '#010x')
f"{12*MiB:#010x}"
f"0x{12*MiB:08x}"
```

You also wanted to separate the digits into blocks of 4. We can use a grouping character to get pretty close, but then we have to add an extra 1 to the width:

```
f"0x{12*MiB:09_x}"
```

… at which point we might as well use `#` again:

```
f"{12*MiB:#011_x}"
```

Now you've got `'0x00c0_0000'`. If you really need spaces between groups instead of underscores, then you'll need to get a bit ugly:

```
f"{12*MiB:#11_x}".replace('_', ' ')
```

(I believe there was a proposal to allow arbitrary grouping characters, but it was rejected, so the only options are `_`, `,`, or `n` for "do whatever my locale says".)

---

So, if you want to print out your table:

```
print( "size        hex '0x' notation")
print(f"1 MiB       {12*MiB:#011_x}")
print(f"12 KiB      {12*KiB:#011_x}")
print(f"128 KiB     {128*KiB:#011_x}")
```

Or you can write a function. While we're at it, let's use an `Enum` instead of a bunch of separate constants:

```
import enum
class Prefixes(enum.Enum):
    Ki = 1024
    Mi = 1024 * Ki
    Gi = 1024 * Mi
    Ti = 1024 * Gi
def printrow(n, prefix):
    label = f"{n} {prefix.name}B"
    print(f"{label:<12}{n * prefix.value:#011_x}")
print("size        hex '0x' notation")
printrow(1, Prefixes.Mi)
printrow(12, Prefixes.Ki)
printrow(128, Prefixes.Ki)
```

This is obviously a lot more extensible, if you want to add more rows to the table.

Comment: great answer! however, you say that `12 MiB = 0x0c0_0000` whereas on the question's table that equals to `0x00c00000`. Are these both the same? I understand that probably my question probably stems from my lack understanding hex in general ..

Comment: @Karim Oops, I forgot that the grouping character counts as part of the width. Edited the answer to fix that. But meanwhile, less, `0x0c0_0000` is the same value as `0x00c0_0000`. Leading zeros don't mean anything, just like in everyday arithmetic `0123` and `00123` are the same number.