# Char array declared with [0x...]

Tags: c, arrays

In program that put data by fgets to char array, array is declared like that:

```
char line[0x400];
```

Is such declaration allow to input more data to array? I dont understand why not to use:

```
char line[400];
```

Comment: "Is such declaration allow" – yes. All numbers are: `0700`, `'B'`, `42`. They are all just numbers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do numbers using 0x notation mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186965/what-do-numbers-using-0x-notation-mean)

Answer (score 1):

Values starting with `0x` are interpreted as hexadecimal values in C and C++. So

> ```
> char line[0x400];
> ```

declares an Array of `char` of 1024 elements and

> ```
> char line[400];
> ```

an Array of `char` of 400 elements.

Answer (score 0):

`0x400` is a [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) representation. Usually, when you see a number in this format `0x<number>` it means the number is represented as an hexadecimal.

Also, [image: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=dec(0x400)].
So yes, the first array is (624 positions) bigger.

Comment: You can also check the conversion here: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=dec(0x400)