# What spelling is that flags enum values having 0x as prefix?

Tags: c#, enums, flags

I have found this `enum` with a `Flags` attribute:

```
    [Flags]
    public enum Technology
    {
       None = 0x0000,
        X1 = 0x0001,
        X2 = 0x0002,
        X3 = 0x0004,
        X4 = 0x0008,
        X5 = 0x0010,
        X6 = 0x0020,       
    }
```

The values assigned to the `enum` members, what spelling is it?

And would that be *the same*?

```
    [Flags]
    public enum Technology
    {
       None = 0,
        X1 = 1,
        X2 = 2,
        X3 = 4,
        X4 = 8,
        X5 = 10,
        X6 = 20,       
    }
```

If yes, why is `X5` not **16** twice the value from `X4`, because that logic takes place from `X1` to `X4`!

Comment: Because 10 is double 8 in hex?

Comment: `0x0020` is *hexadecimal* (please, note `0x` *prefix*) which is `32` *decimal*; so `X5 = 16, X6 = 32`

Comment: `0x` means the number is hexadecimal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do numbers using 0x notation mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186965/what-do-numbers-using-0x-notation-mean)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do numbers using 0x notation mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186965/what-do-numbers-using-0x-notation-mean) and [What does the Flags Enum Attribute mean in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/what-does-the-flags-enum-attribute-mean-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `0x` prefix means *hexadecimal*, not just *decimal*. So the equivalent declarations will be

**hexadecimal** (`0x` prefix)

```
[Flags]
public enum Technology
{
   None = 0x0000,
     X1 = 0x0001,
     X2 = 0x0002,
     X3 = 0x0004,
     X4 = 0x0008,
     X5 = 0x0010, // 0x0010 == 1 * 16 + 0 == 16
     X6 = 0x0020, // 0x0020 == 2 * 16 + 0 == 32       
}
```

**decimal**

```
[Flags]
public enum Technology
{
   None =  0,
     X1 =  1,
     X2 =  2,
     X3 =  4,
     X4 =  8,
     X5 = 16,
     X6 = 32,       
}
```

**binary** (note `0b` prefix)

```
[Flags]
public enum Technology
{
   None = 0b000000,
     X1 = 0b000001,
     X2 = 0b000010,
     X3 = 0b000100,
     X4 = 0b001000,
     X5 = 0b010000,
     X6 = 0b100000,       
}
```

Comment: I think C#8 should enforce `[Flags]` being in binary notation :)

Comment: @tymtam why and how could it be ? a number is a number, no matter how it was written

Answer (score 3):

`0x0000` is 0 in Hexadecimal. Which means that `0x0010` is actually `16` in decimal - making the `x5` and `x6` members of both enums different.

In order to make them the same, in the second `enum` you need the values `16` and `32` for `x5` and `x6`.

The `0x` prefix is what tells the c# compiler that the value is hexadecimal - as documented in the [Integer Literals paragraph in Integral numeric types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types#integer-literals):

> Integer literals can be
>
> - decimal: without any prefix
> - hexadecimal: with the 0x or 0X prefix
> - binary: with the 0b or 0B prefix (available in C# 7.0 and later)