# Calculating hexadecimal values for 7-segment LED on MDA-8086

Tags: c, x86-16, seven-segment-display

I was trying to display 7-segment LED on MDA-8086 kit, but I am stuck at calculating the hexadecimal values for respective digits. I have the code with me, but I don't understand how it actually works.
For example, **0 is represented by hexadecimal value** ***0xc0 [I guess].***
I am wondering, how the values have been calculated here?

C Code for 7-segment LED display:

```
#include"mde8086.h"

int data[11] = { 0xc0, 0xf9, 0xa4, 0xb0, 0x99, 0x92, 0x82, 0xf8, 0x80, 0x90, 0x00 };

void wait(long del)
{
    while( del-- );
}

void main(void)
{
    int *data1;

    /* 8255 -1 Initialization */
    outportb( PPI1_CR, 0x80 );
    outportb( PPI1_B, 0xf0 );
    outportb( PPI1_C, 0x00 );

    //main loop
    do {
        data1 = data;
        while( *data1 != 0x00 )
        {
            outportb( PPI1_A, *data1 );
            wait(30000);
            data1++;
        }
    } while(1);
}
```

The output has been generated from here:

[image: 7-Segment display]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670639/why-are-hexadecimal-numbers-prefixed-with-0x check this stackoverflow question. Also check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186965/what-do-numbers-using-0x-notation-mean/8186974

Comment: My first thought was that `1` is displayed by lighting only 2 segments total, so we can tell that must be `0xc0` (which only has 2 bits set in its binary representation, so segment b = 0x80, c = 0x40 or vice versa).So looping over this array counts up from 1 to 9 then wraps to 0, I guess. But that doesn't work if you look at the rest; there are other patterns with only 1 or a couple bits set, so it must be that the masks are inverted, and clear bits light up the corresponding segment?  Then leaving segment G and the decimal-point unlit could be the top 2 bits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is about how your HW hook-up is, i.e. how the pins of the display is connected to the port and whether it requires a 0 or 1 on the port to turn on a segment.

From your numbers it seems:

1. The port is connected like g, f, e, d, c, b, a That is: a is LSB.
2. The "missing" 8th bit shall always be programmed to 1, i.e. as 8 bit it will be `port = 1gfedcba`
3. It takes a 0 to turn on a segment in the display.

So

```
0xc0 -> 1100.000 -> 1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
                    ^    ^    ^    ^    ^    ^    ^    ^
                    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
                unused   g    f    e    d    c    b    a
                        off  on   on   on   on   on   on
```

which results in a zero on the display.

Now for `0xf9`

```
0xf9 -> 1111.1001
```

so only segment b and c will turn on and the display will display 1

Check the rest yourself.

**EDIT** Looking at the sigment picture, it could be that the 8th bit (that I called "unused") is actually controlling the "DP" part of the segment. This is just a guess but maybe if you write 0x40 to the port, you'll see `0.` on the display.

When you only display numbers, there are many unused combinations. Some of these look like letters, e.g. `H`. So for fun (aka an exercise) you can make the display spell words like "HELLO", "CACAO", "BEEF" and many more.

Comment: Wouldn't `0x40` be `'0.`?  Everything lit except for g.

Comment: @PeterCordes My bad... yes, it'll be `0.` if it's connected as I guess. Thanks for catching and letting me know. :-)

Answer (score 2):

> I am stuck at calculating the hexadecimal values for respective digits.

Sometime a little macro art is fun and illustrative.  It provides a graphical way to define the hex values for `data[]` rather than doing so by hand.

`seven()` takes the 3 rows (strings) and looks for `-`,  `|`,  `.` to form the hex value.  When the corresponding segment is *off*, the value ors in another bit.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define seven(r1,r2,r3) (\
/* Seg A */ (r1[1] == '_' ? 0 : 0x01) |  \
/* Seg B */ (r2[2] == '|' ? 0 : 0x02) |  \
/* Seg C */ (r3[2] == '|' ? 0 : 0x04) |  \
/* Seg D */ (r3[1] == '_' ? 0 : 0x08) |  \
/* Seg E */ (r3[0] == '|' ? 0 : 0x10) |  \
/* Seg F */ (r2[0] == '|' ? 0 : 0x20) |  \
/* Seg G */ (r2[1] == '_' ? 0 : 0x40) |  \
/* Seg DP*/ (r3[3] == '.' ? 0 : 0x80) \
)

int datax[11] = { //
    seven( // Zero
    " _ ",//
    "| |",//
    "|_| "),//
    seven( // One
    "   ",//
    "  |",//
    "  | "),//
    seven( // Two
    " _ ",//
    " _|",//
    "|_  "),//
    };

// Remaining digits left for OP


int main(/*int argc, char *argv[]*/) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    printf("%02X\n", data[i]);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
C0
F9
A4
```

Comment: I might have compacted my representations to 3 rows instead of 5, e.g. top row of zero as `"|-|"`.  That looks nice for 0 but maybe a lot worse for 2.  Still, it keeps the source more compact and is still pretty visually intuitive.  (Overall really neat idea, +1)

Comment: @PeterCordes Good idea. Maybe  `"|_|"` to push the horizontal segment visually down.  What I like about the graphical  approach is that it is easy to extend to other 7-segment characters [figure 2](https://www.engineersgarage.com/electronic-projects/how-to-display-numbers-and-alphabet-on-7-segment-display/).

Comment: @PeterCordes Re-coded with a slight variation on you idea. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Nice, that's even better.  The macros could also be `r1[1] != ' '` so it's the same character every time, without having to match up the right shape to the right position.  It would even be possible to write `(r1[1] != ' ') << 0` and so on, but the ternary is probably better for readability than shifting a boolean->int result.

Comment: @PeterCordes Re: `r1[1] != ' '`, I thought of that too, yet with 2 coding choices: with/without negation, I have found the negation-less code easier to maintain. and [understand](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DBITZw5-HWY)

Comment: Interesting point, that's probably worth the pain of having to get the right symbol for each position.