# Why does a memory address start with 0x?

Tags: c++, c, linux, memory, operating-system

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are Hexadecimal Prefixed as 0x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670639/why-are-hexadecimal-prefixed-as-0x)

Memory addresses are often notated as a hexidecimal value prefixed with `0x`. E.g:

```
> new.env()
<environment: 0x21d36e0>
```

Does the `0x` part mean anything? Where does this notation come from? Is any other value possible instead of `0x`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `0x` is just a notation to let you know the number is in hexadecimal form.

Same as you'd write `042` for an octal number, or `42` for a decimal one.

So - `42 == 052 == 0x2A`.

Comment: The "0" helps the parser know that its dealing with a (constant) number and the "x" stands for hex.

Comment: @JesseGood....then how parser know in case of Decimal number because it is not preceded by 0.

Comment: @Tejendra it knows by exclusion. If it's not `0` or `0x`, it's decimal :)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore...thnx for the clarification :)

Answer (score 7):

Memory address is usually represented in Hexadecimal Form, `0x` is just a notation for Hex number.

Comment: yes, but the preferred form is Hex.