# Why are leading zeroes used to represent octal numbers?

Tags: language-agnostic, history, octal

I've always wondered why leading zeroes (`0`) are used to represent octal numbers, instead of — for example — `0o`. The use of `0o` would be just as helpful, but would not cause as many problems as leading `0`es (e.g. `parseInt('08');` in JavaScript). What are the reason(s) behind this design choice?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

All modern languages import this convention from C, which imported it from B, which imported it from BCPL.

Except BCPL used `#1234` for octal and `#x1234` for hexadecimal. B has departed from this convention because # was an unary operator in B (integer to floating point conversion), so #1234 could not be used, and # as a base indicator was replaced with 0.

The designers of B tried to make the syntax very compact. I guess this is the reason they did not use a two-character prefix.

Answer (score 5):

Worth noting that in Python 3.0, they decided that octal literals must be prefixed with '0o' and the old '0' prefix became a SyntaxError, for the exact reasons you mention in your question

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3127/#removal-of-old-octal-syntax

Answer (score 1):

"0b" is often used for binary rather than for octal.  The leading "0" is, I suspect for "**O** -ctal".

If you know you are going to be parsing octal then use `parseInt('08', 10);` to make it treat the number as base ten.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I'm only wondering why it is used, because it's a little bit confusing for newbies. With `0b` I've made a mistake, fixed to `0o`.

Comment: "Zero" as in "octal"? Hardly. My speculation would be that it was simply the prevalent number format of the day, much like hex is now.

Comment: @triplee: You do realize 0 looks like an O, right? It's not like people haven't been replacing 13773rs with numbers for y34rs.