# BCPL octal numerical constants

Tags: constants, numeric, bcpl

I've been digging into the history of BCPL due to a question I was asked about the reasoning behind using the prefix "0x" for the representation hexadecimal numbers.

In my search I stumbled upon a really good explanation of the history behind this token. ([Why are hexadecimal numbers prefixed with 0x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670639/why-are-hexadecimal-prefixed-as-0x))

From this post, however, another questions sparked:

For octal constants, did BCPL use `8 <digit>` (As per specs: http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/bcpl.pdf) or did it use `#<digit>` (As per http://rabbit.eng.miami.edu/info/bcpl_reference_manual.pdf) or were both of these syntaxes valid in different implementations of the language?

I've also been able to find a second answer here that used the # syntax which further intrigued me in the subject. ([Why are leading zeroes used to represent octal numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483216/why-are-leading-zeroes-used-to-represent-octal-numbers))

Any historical insights are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Might have better luck over at http://cstheory.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There were many slight variations on syntax in BCPL.

For example, while the one we used had 16-bit cells (so that `x!y` gave you the 16-bit *word* from a word address at `x + y` (a word address being half of the byte address), we also had a need to extract from *byte* address and byte values (since we were primarily creating OS and control software on a 6809 byte-addressable CPU).

Hence in addition to:

```
x!y - get word from byte address (x + y) * 2
```

we also had

```
x!%y - get byte from byte address (x * 2) + y
x%!y - get word from byte address x + (y * 2)
x%%y - get byte from byte address x + y
```

I'm pretty certain they were implementation-specific as I never saw them anywhere else. And BCPL was around long before language standards were as important as they are today.

The *canonical* language specification would have been the earlier one from Richards since he wrote the language (and your second document is for the Essex BCPL implementation about a decade later). But keep in mind that Project MAC was the earliest iteration - there were plenty of advancements after that as well.

For example, there's a 2013 revision of the BCPL User Guide (see [Martin's home page](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mr10/)) which specifies `#b`, `#o` and `#x` as prefixes for various non-decimal bases.

Comment: Haven't logged in in quite some time so I hadn't seen this answer, but thank you very much for the answer! Greatly appreciated.