# Power operation in Python

Tags: python

I was playing around with Python. I had a doubt about the `power` operation in Python. So, I tried this:

```
0726**13 = 54609997061205831773270000000000000L 
726**13 = 15565965698792536237226936270158258176L
```

Why is there a difference between these two? I know it might be trivial. But, I could not figure it out. Could someone please explain? Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

It's because an integer constant beginning with 0 is taken to be an octal value.  In this case, 0726 is interpreted as 470:

```
>>> 0726
470
>>> 470**13
54609997061205831773270000000000000L
>>>
```

Comment: Just to make this easier for searching, the problem is occurring because leading zeroes are shorthand in numerous languages for representing octal constants. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483216/why-are-leading-zeroes-used-to-represent-octal-numbers

Answer (score 3):

Numbers starting with 0 in Python are represented in Base 8 (octal numbers). That's why you're getting different results.