# How to add leading 0 to hexadecimal

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex

The code in the bottom adds hexadecimal numbers to a list in the format:

`['0x0', '0x1', ..., '0xa', '0xb', ..., '0xab', ...]`

How can I have the single digit hexadecimal numbers have a leading zero, like this:

`'0x0' '0x0a'`

The code:

```
K = 256

keys = list(itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=8))
for poss in range(K):
    keys[poss] = hex(int(''.join(map(str, keys[poss])), 2))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decorating Hex function to pad zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12638408/decorating-hex-function-to-pad-zeros)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python , Printing Hex removes first 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884677/python-printing-hex-removes-first-0)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of:

```
hex(val)
```

Use:

```
"0x{:02x}".format(val)
```

Alternatively, you can use:

```
"0x%02x" % val
```

Either of these will give you a zero-padded 2-digit hex value, preceded by `0x`.