# What does 'x' in 0x00000000 (or any address) signify?

Tags: language-agnostic, memory-address

Well, for any kind of address, `x` is used to represent it. 
What does `x` actually signify?

Comment: The origin is probably simply that 'X' rhymes with hex.

Comment: After reading the answers, I could make out, `x` represents that the number is in hexadecimal. Well, what to use to show if a number in in any other format(for instance say decimal).

Comment: @Raedwald. This asks for answer, that for reason. Had it been shown in search results, i would not ask this question. thnx pal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not just for addresses. The `0x` prefix is used for hexadecimal literals in, as far as I know, all C-style languages (C, Java, C++, Objective-C, C#...) and probably others as well.

`0x10` is, for instance, 10 hexadecimal, or 16 decimal.

More information is available in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670639/why-are-hexadecimal-prefixed-as-0x).

Answer (score 0):

It means it is in hexadecimal format, i.e a number with a base of 16, instead of 10, as are usual.

Answer (score 0):

`0x` is te prefix used to represent numbers in hexadecimal notation.

In this case, `0x00000000` is the value used to represent null memory adresses (equivalent to the keyword `null` for high level languages like Java, C# and many others).