# Hexadecimal color system

Tags: php, colors, hex

I'm trying to allocate a color for an image using [imagecolorallocate()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorallocate.php). The red, green and blue parameters can either be integers between 0 and 255 or hexadecimals between 0x00 and 0xFF. For example:

Decimal way:

```
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
```

Hexadecimal way:

```
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);
```

In the hexadecimal colour system, I know that `#000000` is black. The first two digits `00` are the red value, the second two digits `00` are the green and the third two digits `00` are the blue.

I notice each `00` in `imagecolorallocate($im, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00)` is prefixed with an `0x`. Can someone help me understand what the `0x` part is?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are Hexadecimal Prefixed as 0x?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670639/why-are-hexadecimal-prefixed-as-0x)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Answer (score 2):

The 0x tells whatever is reading the values to expect hex rather than decimal. This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670639/why-are-hexadecimal-prefixed-as-0x) article might help :)