# PHPMD5 encrytion in sql

Tags: c#, sql-server, encryption

I need your help on implementing an encryption process from C# code to sql server.

Here is the method I get in c# code :

```
    private static string GetPhpMD5(string strPlain) 
    {
        ASCIIEncoding UE = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] HashValue, MessageBytes = UE.GetBytes(strPlain);
        MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        string strHex = "";

        HashValue = md5.ComputeHash(MessageBytes);
        foreach(byte b in HashValue) 
        {
            strHex += String.Format("{0:x2}", b);
        }
        return strHex;
    } /* GetPhpMD5 */

    GetPhpMD5("nvhG#hdsdsqsd3H");
```

And so I want to do the same in sql server. I try this but not giving me the same result :

```
select Hashbytes('MD5', CONVERT(varchar(max),'nvhG#hdsdsqsd3H', 2) )
```

> Result in c# : f4ae6882a7e2aff90d58a29100c5bbf6
>
> Result in sql server : 0xF4AE6882A7E2AFF90D58A29100C5BBF6

Can anyone help me on this please.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: looks totally the same to me

Comment: Apart from one being in upper and the other in lower, and being in a binary/hex, they appear identical. I don't really see what the problem is here. The algorithm appears to be the same.

Comment: Just uppercase the C# result? Maybe add the "0x" if you need it? Hex values do not care about casing.

Comment: 1) `0x` is a prefix indicating "what follows is hexadecimal".  It is optional, depending on the context.  2) casing of hexadecimal values does not matter.  3) Even if it did matter, you know how to upper/lower case and prefix strings, don't you?

Comment: For further information on the "0x", see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670639/why-are-hexadecimal-numbers-prefixed-with-0x).

Comment: Thanks for answers, I will try to see that

Comment: Also, encryption != hashing. Encryption implies the possibility of decryption, while (strong) hashing should be one-way-only. (MD5 is fast, but not cryptographically strong)

Answer (score 0):

Just find this way that looks good :

```
select SUBSTRING(MASTER.dbo.Fn_varbintohexstr(Hashbytes('MD5', CONVERT(varchar(max),'nvhG#hdsdsqsd3H', 2) )), 3, 8000)
```

Thanks for your help.