# Why does `"0a".to_i(16)` return `10`?

Tags: ruby

I'm confused about the optional argument for `to_i`.
Specifically, what "base" means, and how it impacts the method in this example:

```
"0a".to_i(16) #=> 10
```

I have trouble with the optional argument in regards to the string the method is called on. I thought that the return value would just be an integer value of `0`.

Comment: Base 16 is also known as hexadecimal. 0a is a hexadecimal number.

Comment: There is nothing Ruby-specific or even programming-specific about this. It is just the normal standard meaning of the word "base", in other words, it's just middle school level maths.

Comment: Exactly as Jorg W Mittag says. And often, it is elementary school level math for some students.

Answer (score 4):

Simple answer: It's because `0a` or `a` in [Hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) is equal to `10` in [Decimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal).

And `base`, in other word [Radix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix) means the number of unique digits in a numeral system.

In Decimal, we have `0` to `9`, 10 digits to represent numbers.
In Hexadecimal, there're 16 digits instead, apart from `0` to `9`, we use `a` to `f` to represent the conceptual numbers of `10` to `15`.

You can test it like this:

```
"a".to_i(16)
#=> 10
"b".to_i(16)
#=> 11
"f".to_i(16)
#=> 15
"g".to_i(16)
#=> 0  # Because it's not a correct hexadecimal digit/number.
'2c'.to_i(16)
#=> 44
'2CH2'.to_i(16)
#=> 44  # Extraneous characters past the end of a valid number are ignored, and it's case insensitive.
9.to_s.to_i(16)
#=> 9
10.to_s.to_i(16)
#=> 16
```

In other words, `10` in Decimal is equal to `a` in Hexadecimal.
And `10` in Hexadecimal is equal to `16` in Decimal. (Doc for [to_i](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-to_i))

Note that usually we use `0x` precede to Hexadecimal numbers:

```
"0xa".to_i(16)
#=> 10
"0x100".to_i(16)
#=> 256
```

Btw, you can just use these representations in Ruby:

```
num_hex = 0x100
#=> 256
num_bin = 0b100
#=> 4
num_oct = 0o100
#=> 64
num_dec = 0d100
#=> 100
```

He**x**adecimal, **b**inary, **o**ctonary, **d**ecimal (this one, `0d` is superfluous of course, just use in some cases for clarification.)

Comment: Nice explanation! Above will work with case insensitivity & continue to take characters till it get invalid character e.g. '2CH2'  will take '2C' in to account.

Comment: @ray  Thanks, added it to the examples :)

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth explanation, @Tiw! I've learned something new today.

Comment: I understand how we get #=> 256 from ("0x100".to_i(16)), but how could we interpret this in a simple way? Also, is there any reason why '0x' proceeds Hex numbers?

Comment: It's a convention... `0x` indicate you want to use an Hex number. [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670639/why-are-hexadecimal-numbers-prefixed-with-0x) an explanation

Comment: @Nano  `0x100 => 1 * 16^2`. he**x**adecimal, **b**inary, **o**ctonary, so we use `0x`, `0b` and `0o`.

Comment: @Nano: There is no specific reason. The standard way to write it is to attach the base as a subscript postfix or prefix. However, most programming languages don't support subscript (the only one I can remember off the top of my head is Fortress). Therefore, some languages use parentheses (e.g. `1234DEADBEEF(16)`) or underscores (`1234DEADBEEF_16`). But prefixes are also common, e.g. `0x` for 16, `0o` for 8, `0b` for 2, `0d` for 10. In Ruby, octal numbers can also be prefixed with the number `0`, i.e. `10` is 10 decimal, but `010` is 8 decimal, and `0x10` is 16 decimal, `0b10` is 2 decimal.