# why does vc++ not behave like my calculator

Tags: visual-c++

I have a simple question.If I wanted top add some hex values in vc++
like 0x140000000 and 0x02F61570 my calculator says the result is 
0x142f61570, but in my code ,if I add these two numbers I only get 
0x42f61570. Where could the problem be ?

I have already tried with maybe some other values than storing the hex in DWORD ,but the result is the same.

```
DWORD base = 0x140000000;
DWORD address = 0x02F61570;
DWORD next = base + address;
printf("0x%x\n",next);
```

the result of the operation in my code are => 0x42f61570 as opposed to my calculator ,which says 0x142f61570

Comment: Have you tried `DWORD sum = 0x142f61570;`  ?   What happens?

Comment: @DaveS: No.... the prefix for hexadecimal is `0x` not `0x0`.  And octal literals never contain an `x`

Comment: Ah, thanks -- I never use octal so I'm probably thinking of something ancient like Turbo C++ for DOS  :)

Comment: @DaveS: I don't think Turbo C++ is old enough to get octal vs hexadecimal literals wrong... those have been that way since C (not ++).

Comment: Yep, my brain was just misfiring - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670639/why-are-hexadecimal-numbers-prefixed-with-0x

Answer (score 0):

`DWORD` is a typedef for a 32-bit unsigned integer, and operations on unsigned integers in C++ are performed using modular arithmetic.  `printf` is showing you the real value of `next`, and that value is the correct result of `base + address` when using arithmetic modulo 2<sup>32</sup>.

In fact, the original initialization `DWORD base = 0x140000000;` already reduced the value modulo 2<sup>32</sup>.  Didn't your compiler generate a warning for an out-of-range constant initializer?

---

The expected output is achieved if you use 64-bit variables.

```
DWORD64 base = 0x140000000;
DWORD address = 0x02F61570;
DWORD64 next = base + address;
printf("0x%I64x\n", next);
```

Comment: I do believe you're a `typedef` as well.

Comment: well I think I have gotten no compiler warnings, but like you said ,that could be the problem.I have tried LONG64 and DWORD64 ,but to no avail.

Comment: @DenisMuhic: With `DWORD64` it works for me, see: https://rextester.com/TFZVT39756

Comment: Ok thanks ,I can see. Now I can get the right values, but there seem to be more problems with the app. But thanks for answering..