# Can't solve C2660 and C2065 Errors

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm following an online tutorial to learn how to code and make video games, but my problem is the tutorial is about 7 years old and some of the instructions give issues, even when I break down and try copying the sample code directly.

More specifically, my issue comes from trying to color in my circles, as it says the function doesn't take 3 arguments, and there is this "check to see if the window is open" function at the end that says the "Event identifier is undeclared" and I'm also not sure the function's purpose.

```
int main()
{
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1000, 1000), "Round Bounce");

//Circles
sf::CircleShape circleRed(int 100);
sf::CircleShape circlePink(int 100);
sf::CircleShape circleWhite(int 100);

//Colors
//THIS IS WHERE MY ISSUE IS.
//I used to have these formatted as (255, 0, 0));

circleRed.setFillColor(sf::Color(FF0000));
circlePink.setFillColor(sf::Color(FF8282));
circleWhite.setFillColor(sf::Color(FFFFFF));

//Location
float xPink = 200;
float yPink = 200;

float xWhite = 300;
float yWhite = 300;

circleRed.setPosition(100, 100);
circlePink.setPosition(xPink, yPink);
circleWhite.setPosition(xWhite, yWhite);

//Open Check
while (window.isOpen())
{
    //THIS IS THE OTHER LOCATION I'M HAVING TROUBLES WITH
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();
    }
    window.clear();
    window.draw(circleRed);
    window.draw(circlePink);
    window.draw(circleWhite);
    window.display();
}
return 0;

}
```

> C2660 'sf::Shape:setFillColor':function does not take 3 arguments
>   C2065 'Event':Undeclared Identifier

Comment: `sf::CircleShape circleRed(int 100);` should be `sf::CircleShape circleRed(100);` assuming it takes 1 parameter. The next two as well. The nice thing about errors is they come with line numbers so you don't need to guess.

Comment: I think `circleRed.setFillColor(sf::Color(FF0000));` should be `circleRed.setFillColor(sf::Color(FF,00,00));`

Comment: The advice from @RetiredNinja is correct. The `int` does not belong.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I tried following your advice, but the error message says its for "circleRed.setFillColor(sf::Color(FF0000));"

Comment: For the event error you need to include the header for `sf::Event` which is `#include <Event.hpp>`

Comment: @drescherjm I added the commas, but the error remains

Comment: @drescherjm I added the header but the error is still the same

Comment: Did you fix this `sf::CircleShape circleRed(int 100);` to `sf::CircleShape circleRed(100);`

Comment: If the errors are not changing did you save the file before compiling? Seems like you are compiling the old code.

Comment: @RetiredNinja If you have an answer, post it in the answer section where it belongs.

Comment: Have you considered reading a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/5910058) or two? C++ is not really a language suited for learning by trial and error and online tutorials, it's *much* too complex for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 bugs that I see in the code as presented and one other bug in the listed errors.

In `sf::CircleShape circleRed(int 100);` and the 2 lines following the `int` does not belong with the parameter. So those lines should be:

```
sf::CircleShape circleRed(100);
sf::CircleShape circlePink(100);
sf::CircleShape circleWhite(100);
```

Then below in the `circleRed.setFillColor(sf::Color(FF0000));` the color format is not correct according to the [documentation](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Color.php).

```
circleRed.setFillColor(sf::Color(0xFF,0x00,0x00));
circlePink.setFillColor(sf::Color(0xFF,0x82,0x82));
circleWhite.setFillColor(sf::Color(0xFF,0xFF,0xFF));
```

Since the numbers are given in hex you proceed them with `0x` see here for more info: [Why are hexadecimal numbers prefixed with 0x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670639/why-are-hexadecimal-numbers-prefixed-with-0x)

Also the following error

> C2065 'Event':Undeclared Identifier

indicates that the header for [`sf::Event`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Event.php) is not included. Add

```
#include <Event.hpp>
```

at the top of the cpp file containing main.

Comment: Your advice DID work! For some reason, my debugger was running a .hpp file that didn't exist! I still have some bugs, but I think I can get these myself! Thanks!

Comment: @Scheff Okay, I think I've done that now, I pressed a green check next to their answer.