# Unicodes for gitmoji

Tags: javascript, unicode

I was reviewing a code where they author did something like this

```
const emojis: Array<Icon | undefined> | undefined = emojiSet
  .map((emoji) => {
    if (emoji.name && emoji.unified) {
      const codePoints = emoji.unified
        .split("-")
        .map((token) => Number("0x" + token));
        
      return {
        name: emoji.name,
        value: String.fromCodePoint(...codePoints),
        index: emoji.unified,
      };
    }
    return undefined;
  })
  .filter(Boolean);
```

To understand the code, I went through this [repo](https://github.com/iamcal/emoji-data) (which is what the above is using to iterate over the json)

Here, in the example unified is  `"unified": "261D-FE0F",`

When he does this,

```
   const codePoints = emoji.unified
        .split("-")
        .map((token) => Number("0x" + token));
```

He is iterating over `261D-FE0F` and mapping it to number  `.map((token) => Number("0x" + token));`

**[Question]** Here I am unable to comprehend that why is he adding "Ox" to the number? how can we determine using unicode that this is going to be emoji?

THis is [unicdoe blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji#Unicode_blocks) from wiki (if it associates with my question in anyway)

Comment: The `0x` prefix is used to denote a hexadecimal number. Compare: `console.log(0x145, 145)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are hexadecimal numbers prefixed with 0x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670639/why-are-hexadecimal-numbers-prefixed-with-0x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the numbers are in hex. `0x` is a prefix used to indicate hex numbers. `Number("261D")` is `NaN`, but `Number("0x261D")` is 9757.

Other prefixes available in JavaScript are `0b` (binary, e.g. `0b11` is 3) and `0o` (octal, e.g. `0o11` is 9).