# (JAVA)Why we got an integer when we print number in hexadecimal notation?

Tags: java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1miE.png)Example:
sout(OxBD);
Output: 189

I don't really understand why does compiler converts different representation of a number to integer. Why not boolean? When I try to cast to double(boolean was here, wrote by mistake...) I got an error, also don't know why. With char it works.
I attached the photo below.

Comment: There is context missing. What are you trying to print? Is "OxBD" a string? Is there a variable you're printing something from?

Comment: Im just learning the language in depth. Just curious about it.

Comment: You can indeed edit your post; while you can't embed, the website will automatically link to imgur.

Comment: @allrightallrightallright `0xBD` is the hexadecimal integer literal for the number `189`. The "value" of `0xBD` is still an integer.

Comment: I didn't...im rookie..I attached the photo as a proof.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake; I copied "OxBD" instead of "0xBD" (as that is what your post said as of writing). You are right @allrightallrightallright. I have deleted my earlier comment.

Comment: Do you the answer to my question tho?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are hexadecimal numbers prefixed with 0x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670639/why-are-hexadecimal-numbers-prefixed-with-0x)

Comment: Do you mean why doesn't the value print as hex? How it prints has nothing to do with how you assign a value.

Comment: Not really. I don't understand why compiler converts the 0xBD to integer and gives me the result as int...

Comment: Oh wow, after reading "hexadecimal integer" it gave more sense to me.

Comment: damn, very interesting...where can I read about it more?

Comment: More about it: [JLS § 3.10.1 – integer literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"0xBD" is an integer, which explains why it's converted to hexadecimal by Java. You can't convert to boolean, as 189 isn't something that can be converted to boolean (which can store only two values, 0 and 1).

189 *can* be stored as a char though; what you get is the ASCII character representation of 189.

Comment: 0xBD is an integer? So basically it's just a representation of an integer?

Comment: Indeed, just in a different base (base 16 instead of base 10). This is also called as hexadecimal.

Comment: But still a bit confused why compiler converts to decimal(?). Why it cannot just print in hexadecimal?

Comment: Because Java recognises that 0xBD is an integer, and (essentially) converts it to its decimal equivalent before printing. It doesn't have a "since I initialised as a hexadecimal, print it only in hexadecimal" mode.

Comment: `System.out.println`, when applied to an `int`, always prints it in decimal.